# equations in multiple lines

Tags: equations, arrays

I'm using the following code to generate the second figure.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle \min_{W, S}J(W,S)=\frac{\sum^n_{i,j=1}\norm{W^{T}(x_{i}-x_{j})}^2S_{ij}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\norm{W^Tx_{i}}^2}+\mu\norm{S}^2 \\ \\
\displaystyle \text{s.t.} \; W^TW=I \\
\displaystyle \sum^n_{j=1}S_{ij}=1, i = 1, \dots, n
\displaystyle \\S_{ij}\geq0, i,j = 1, \dots, n
\end{array} 
\label{piel2}
\end{equation}
```

But Actually, I'd like to have first figure where the 's.t.' is before all of the constrains. How can I get it?

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: don't use `array` to make multi-line displays. Use the alignments in the `amsmath` package. `array` is designed to typeset arrays/matrices rather than full expressions.

Comment: And please make your code compilable and complete with `\documentclass{..}` and ending at `\end{document}` with relevant packages.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\min_{W, S}J(W,S) & =\frac{\sum^n_{i,j=1}\norm{W^{T}(x_{i}-x_{j})}^2 S_{ij}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\norm{W^Tx_{i}}^2}+μ \norm{S}^2 \\
\text{s.t.} &\\
   &{}W^TW=I \\
&{}\sum^n_{j=1}S_{ij}=1, & \hphantom{,j} i  = 1, \dots, n \\
&{}S_{ij}\geq 0,  & i,j = 1, \dots, n
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\min_{W, S}J(W,S) & =\frac{\sum^n_{i,j=1}\norm{W^{T}(x_{i}-x_{j})}^2 S_{ij}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\norm{W^Tx_{i}}^2}+μ \norm{S}^2 \\
& \text{s.t.\qquad}  
\begin{aligned}[t]
W^TW=I \\
\sum^n_{j=1}S_{ij}=1, & \hphantom{,j} i  = 1, \dots, n \\
S_{ij}\geq 0,  \,\quad & i,j = 1, \dots, n
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're `legendary`, Harish, congratulations! :)

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you for the kind words Chris. :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to make what you want:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \min_{W, S}J(W,S) & =\frac{\sum^n_{i,j=1}\norm{W^{T}(x_{i}-x_{j})}^2 S_{ij}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\norm{W^Tx_{i}}^2}+μ \norm{S}^2 \\
    & \text{s.t.} \begin{cases}
       W^TW=I \\
    \sum^n_{j=1}S_{ij}=1, & \hphantom{,j} i  = 1, \dots, n \\
    S_{ij}\geq 0,  & i,j = 1, \dots, n
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\min_{W, S}J(W,S)=\frac{\sum^n_{i,j=1} \rVert{W^{T}(x_{i}-x_{j})\rVert}^2S_{ij}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\rVert{W^Tx_{i}}\rVert^2}+\mu \rVert{S}\rVert^2 \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\hspace{50mm}such that,
\begin{eqnarray}
W^TW=I  \nonumber \\
\sum^n_{j=1}S_{ij}=1, i = 1, \dots, n\nonumber\\
S_{ij}\geq0, i,j = 1, \dots, n \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]